# Is there any way to modify the magento php code (backend)?

Tags: magento2, php, backend, code

In magento 2:
Where can I modify the login code?
How can I see the user that is logged in?
Where are the php files that control the backend?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you actually want to accomplish or what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want to modify the login code (php) and I want to know how I can do it so that when I log in I automatically go to the page of an article (ip/producto.html)